# How to call api with unirest before setState

Tags: reactjs, unirest

In my componentDidMount I call random quotes api and it displays to the console correctly. I then call set state, but set state is getting called before unirest call to the api. How can I wait until the api call is complete to call setState?

```
  state = {
    quote: '',
    author: '',
    category: ''
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    let data = [];
    unirest.get("https://andruxnet-random-famous-quotes.p.mashape.com/?cat=famous&count=2")
    .header("X-Mashape-Key", Mashable_Key)
    .header("X-Mashape-Host", "andruxnet-random-famous-quotes.p.mashape.com")
    .end(function (result) {
      data = result.body[0];
      console.log(data)
    })

    this.setState({
      quote: data.quote,
      author: data.author,
      category: data.category
    })

   console.log(this.state)

  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call setState after getting the result from the API, please have a look on below code:
    `componentDidMount() {
       let data = [];
       unirest.get("https://andruxnet-random-famous-quotes.p.mashape.com/?cat=famous&count=2")
       .header("X-Mashape-Key", Mashable_Key)
       .header("X-Mashape-Host", "andruxnet-random-famous-quotes.p.mashape.com")
       .end(function (result) {
       data = result.body[0];
       console.log(data)
       this.setState({
          quote: data.quote,
          author: data.author,
          category: data.category
      })
    })
  }`

Comment: I've tried this, but I receive an error. "TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined"

Comment: Nevermind it work once I added the arrow function after end. => .  Thank you for your input.